# Does * selector affect performance seriously?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Sometimes i find very usefull doing this:

```
.someclass > *{}
```

to select all the direct children of an object.
Problem is that I read that selectors get evaluated from right to left so that is telling to get every html element from the begining and then filter.
Can this cause serious performance issues if done multiple times?

I also do this for my css reset:

```
*, *:after, *:before{}
```

EDIT: Is there a way to select all direct children without using the * selector?

Comment: I honestly think there are much worse performance hogs in JavaScript and number and size of requests. I'd avoid that reset tho. Ime it causes more grief than it helps. Personally I use nothing but normalize.css nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very un-performant selector, but actually the performance impact is negligible. That is, of course without using properties like box shadows, animation on the universal selector. That will actually slow down the site as well.

So, if you know what you're doing, you can use the universal selector, but if you like to optimize your site performance best as possible, I would recommend you to avoid using it.

Comment: is there a way to mesure this?

Comment: Dev tools. Further reading: http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439817/tools-to-measure-the-effect-of-individual-css-rules-on-page-rendering-speed

Comment: Judjing by that page, it really doesn't matter much as there is only a 20% diference between the fastest and the slowest, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but depending on how large your dom is, the values get larger and larger. Still almost negligible, but if you are performance orientated I recommend you to stay away from the universal selector.